# separate threads in pygtk application

Tags: python, multithreading, pygtk

I'm having some problems threading my pyGTK application.  I give the thread some time to complete its task, if there is a problem I just continue anyway but warn the user.  However once I continue, this thread stops until gtk.main_quit is called.  This is confusing me.

The relevant code:

```
class MTP_Connection(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, HOME_DIR, username):
        self.filename = HOME_DIR + "mtp-dump_" + username
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        #test run
        for i in range(1, 10):
            time.sleep(1)
            print i
```

..........................

```
start_time = time.time()
conn = MTP_Connection(self.HOME_DIR, self.username)
conn.start()
progress_bar = ProgressBar(self.tree.get_widget("progressbar"),
                           update_speed=100, pulse_mode=True)
while conn.isAlive():
    while gtk.events_pending():
        gtk.main_iteration()
    if time.time() - start_time > 5:
        self.write_info("problems closing connection.")
        break
#after this the program continues normally, but my conn thread stops
```

Comment: I feel your pain.  I've been through the threading game with pygtk before myself!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Firstly, don't subclass `threading.Thread`, use `Thread(target=callable).start()`.

Secondly, and probably the cause of your apparent block is that `gtk.main_iteration` takes a parameter `block`, which defaults to `True`, so your call to `gtk.main_iteration` will actually block when there are no events to iterate on. Which can be solved with:

```
gtk.main_iteration(block=False)
```

However, there is no real explanation why you would use this hacked up loop rather than the actual gtk main loop. If you are already running this inside a main loop, then I would suggest that you are doing the wrong thing. I can expand on your options if you give us a bit more detail and/or the complete example.

Thirdly, and this only came up later: Always always *always* ***always*** make sure you have called `gtk.gdk.threads_init` in any pygtk application with threads. GTK+ has different code paths when running threaded, and it needs to know to use these.

I wrote [a small article about pygtk and threads](http://unpythonic.blogspot.com/2007/08/using-threads-in-pygtk.html) that offers you a small abstraction so you never have to worry about these things. That post also includes a progress bar example.

Comment: From your page I found that I am supposed to write:
gtk.gdk.threads_init() which I never did.  It works now.
What is the reason I shouldn't I subclass threading.Thread? All the examples I looked at do this.

Comment: I'm running in the mainloop, but I don't want to continue until I know if the thread will fail or not, which is why I wrote this inner loop.

Comment: There is just no need to subclass it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/660961/overriding-python-threading-thread-run/660974#660974

Comment: Ok, but as long as you realise that the rest of your UI won't get updates during that period.