# GUI update with real-time UDP data in python

Tags: python, multithreading, real-time, pygtk, glade

I am using Glade ,python and pygtk to develop a very basic GUI which will update itself depending on Realtime data received over a UDP socket.The data packets received come every 256ms.
As I understand,I will need to receive this data using a thread to keep my GUI responsive while receiving the data.I have tried to do so.As a result The GUI opens but I dont get any OP from my UDP (dpmserver thread).
I have tried the dpmserver module seperately,it works fine.
I am new to threading.Actually this id my first program with threads in python.
How can I keep my GUI responsive and at the same time receive the data?
The code is as follows:

```
TMSTART=41
PACKETSIZE=133
FIELD=9
TMEND=(PACKETSIZE-1)-FIELD
import socket
import sys
import string
import os.path
import urllib2
import string
import linecache
from pprint import pprint,pformat
import threading
try:
  import pygtk
  pygtk.require("2.0")
except:
  print "You need to install pyGTK or GTKv2 or set your PYTHONPATH correctly"
  sys.exit(1)

import gtk
import gtk.glade

def procpack(data):


        TMlist=[]
        for i in range(TMSTART,TMEND,FIELD):
                field=data[i+1:i+FIELD+1]
                try:
                        if field=='\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00':
                                return TMlist
                except:
                        pass
                TMlist.append([field[0:8],field[8]])

def dpmserver():
        server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        server_socket.bind(("", 5123))

        print"UDPServer Waiting for client on port 5123"
        bytestack=[];
        while 1:
                data, address = server_socket.recvfrom(512)
                print "( " ,address[0], " " , address[1] , " ) said : ", data," length:",len(data)

                print procpack(data)


class AppParafin:
  def __init__(self):


        self.gladefile = 'dpm.glade'
        windowname = 'Deployment Monitor'# This must match the window name in glade
        self.wTree = gtk.glade.XML(self.gladefile, windowname)# object for acessing widgets
        t=threading.Thread(target=dpmserver)
        t.start()
        self.op=self.wTree.get_widget('Deployment Monitor')
        self.op.show()

app = AppParafin()
gtk.main()
```

Comment: It looks like you're basically doing it right, but have a look here on issues with threading and pygtk http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12708039/urllib2-opener-hangs-if-run-inside-a-thread/12773155#12773155 and here for a simple threading example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8583975/stop-pygtk-gui-from-locking-up-during-long-running-process/8584339#comment17192332_8584339

Comment: You may use threads organization like in my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13122984/pythonpygtk-transport-data-to-threading/13400078#13400078