# How to manage python threads results?

Tags: python, multithreading, arrays

I am using this code:

```
def startThreads(arrayofkeywords):
    global i
    i = 0
    while len(arrayofkeywords):
        try:
            if i<maxThreads:
                keyword = arrayofkeywords.pop(0)
                i = i+1
                thread = doStuffWith(keyword)
                thread.start()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            sys.exit()
    thread.join()
```

for threading in python, I have almost everything done, but I dont know how to manage the results of each thread, on each thread I have an array of strings as result, how can I join all those arrays into one safely? Because, I if I try writing into a global array, two threads could be writing at the same time.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First, you actually need to save *all* those `thread` objects to call `join()` on them.  As written, you're saving only the last one of them, and then only if there isn't an exception.

An easy way to do multithreaded programming is to give each thread all the data it needs to run, and then have it not write to anything outside that working set.  If all threads follow that guideline, their writes will not interfere with each other.  Then, once a thread has finished, have the *main thread only* aggregate the results into a global array.  This is know as "fork/join parallelism."

If you subclass the Thread object, you can give it space to store that return value without interfering with other threads.  Then you can do something like this:

```
class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, ...):
        self.result = []
        ...

def main():
    # doStuffWith() returns a MyThread instance
    threads = [ doStuffWith(k).start() for k in arrayofkeywords[:maxThreads] ]
    for t in threads:
        t.join()
        ret = t.result
        # process return value here
```

**Edit:**

After looking around a bit, it seems like the above method [isn't the preferred way to do threads in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660961/overriding-python-threading-thread-run).  The above is more of a Java-esque pattern for threads.  Instead you could do something like:

```
def handler(outList)
    ...
    # Modify existing object (important!)
    outList.append(1)
    ...

def doStuffWith(keyword):
    ...
    result = []
    thread = Thread(target=handler, args=(result,))
    return (thread, result)

def main():
    threads = [ doStuffWith(k) for k in arrayofkeywords[:maxThreads] ]
    for t in threads:
        t[0].start()
    for t in threads:
        t[0].join()
        ret = t[1]
        # process return value here
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer is the easiest for me to understand, will try it right now.

Answer (score 14):

Use a [`Queue.Queue`](http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html) instance, which is intrinsically thread-safe.  Each thread can `.put` its results to that global instance when it's done, and the main thread (when it knows all working threads are done, by `.join`ing them for example as in @unholysampler's answer) can loop `.get`ting each result from it, and use each result to `.extend` the "overall result" list, until the queue is emptied.

**Edit**: there are other big problems with your code -- if the maximum number of threads is less than the number of keywords, it will never terminate (you're trying to start a thread per keyword -- never less -- but if you've already started the max numbers you loop forever to no further purpose).

Consider instead using a **threading pool**, kind of like the one in [this recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/203871-a-generic-programming-thread-pool/), except that in lieu of queueing callables you'll queue the keywords -- since the callable you want to run in the thread is the same in each thread, just varying the argument.  Of course that callable will be changed to peel something from the incoming-tasks queue (with `.get`) and `.put` the list of results to the outgoing-results queue when done.

To terminate the N threads you could, after all keywords, `.put` N "sentinels" (e.g. `None`, assuming no keyword can be `None`): a thread's callable will exit if the "keyword" it just pulled is `None`.

More often than not, `Queue.Queue` offers the best way to organize threading (and multiprocessing!) architectures in Python, be they generic like in the recipe I pointed you to, or more specialized like I'm suggesting for your use case in the last two paragraphs.

Answer (score 3):

You need to keep pointers to each thread you make. As is, your code only ensures the last created thread finishes. This does not imply that all the ones you started before it have also finished.

```
def startThreads(arrayofkeywords):
    global i
    i = 0
    threads = []
    while len(arrayofkeywords):
        try:
            if i<maxThreads:
                keyword = arrayofkeywords.pop(0)
                i = i+1
                thread = doStuffWith(keyword)
                thread.start()
                threads.append(thread)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            sys.exit()
    for t in threads:
        t.join()
    //process results stored in each thread
```

This also solves the problem of write access because each thread will store it's data locally. Then after all of them are done, you can do the work to combine each threads local data.

Comment: And how would I access each thread local data? because threads are being created/finishing all the time, is not like always the same 10 threads.

Comment: By local data, I was alluding to Karmastan's solution. Based on what you posted in the question, it looks like you make N threads, start then, and then join them. Given that pattern accessing the local data after the thread finishes will work fine. If you want things to be much more dynamic, then you will want to look at the answers that discuss thread pooling and storing the results in the data queue.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this question is a little bit old, but the best way to do this is not to harm yourself too much in the way proposed by other colleagues :)

Please read the reference on [Pool](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=pool#module-multiprocessing.pool). This way you will fork-join your work:

```
def doStuffWith(keyword):
    return keyword + ' processed in thread'

def startThreads(arrayofkeywords):
    pool = Pool(processes=maxThreads)
    result = pool.map(doStuffWith, arrayofkeywords)
    print result
```

Comment: It's worth noting that `Pool` uses `multiprocessing` instead of `threading`, which uses separate memory space for each process and therefore slower than threads. Use `from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool` for the threading equivalent of `Pool`.

Answer (score 0):

Writing into a global array is fine if you use a semaphore to protect the critical section. You 'acquire' the lock when you want to append to the global array, then 'release' when you are done. This way, only one thread is every appending to the array.

Check out http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html and search for semaphore for more info.

```
sem = threading.Semaphore()
...
sem.acquire()
# do dangerous stuff
sem.release()
```

Answer (score 0):

try some semaphore's methods, like acquire and release.. 
http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html