# Python passing variable into thread

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm using the threading module to control threads that send data through sockets and what not, however I can't find a suitable solution to pass data into the thread to work with. I've tried things such as [Overriding python threading.Thread.run()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660961/overriding-python-threading-thread-run/660974#660974) but can't seem to get it working. If anyone has any suggestions I'd be happy to try anything :)

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are thinking about this backwards. Forget about the fact that it happens to be a thread that's sending the data through the sockets. The data doesn't need to get to the thread, it needs to get to the logic that sends data on the socket.

For example, you can have a queue that holds things that need to be sent through the socket. The socket write code pulls messages from the queue and sends them out the socket. The other code puts messages on this queue. The code that needs to send messages to the socket shouldn't know or care that there happens to be a thread that does the sending.

Answer (score 1):

Use message queues for this. Python has the `Queue` module for passing data between threads, but if you use a third party library like 0MQ http://www.zeromq.org instead, then you can split the threads into separate processes and it will work the same way.

Multiprocessing is easier to do than threading, but if you have to use threading, avoid locking and sharing data as much as you can. Instead use a prewritten module like `Queue` to limit the ways in which subtle bugs can arise.